# Recover Source Code with ABI & Bytecode?

Tags: abi, bytecode, recovery

I stupidly lost my smart-contract source code due to a PC crash and was unable to recover it. I have an old version saved but much of the work I've done is lost. Luckily, I have the ABI,  ByteCode, and all the necessary addresses.

Is it possible to rebuild the source-code of my smart-contract with all of this information? I was looking at various tools online for decompiling bytecode but I found nothing conclusive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get the exact actual source code. But what you can get is *some* sort of a source code, by reverse engineering the bytecode. It won't be pretty, and the process may be difficult, but at least in theory it should work.